# What will happen if we re-add a deleted guest account, can the guest account access the sites shared with him previously

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, user, external-users

I have the following case inside our office 365 & sharepoint online:-

1. I have a classic team site collection which contain 40 sub-sites. the site collection allow sharing with external users (existing & new).
2. now we have shared many sites with different external users, and we do not keep track of which site is shared with which external user. and sometimes we receive requests to prevent an external user from accessing the sites, where we remove his account from the Office 365 >> Active users list >> which will move the guest account to the "Deleted users" list:-
   [image]
3. but one thing i noted, is that when we remove the user from the "Active users" list, then the username will stay inside the sharepoint group. but the guest account will not be able to access the site.

First question, but since the deleted external username will stay inside the SP security group, so what will happen if in the future we share a new site with the same external user email address. Will the external user be able to access the old site which have his email address added inside its security group ?

Second question, now the only way to remove the username from all the sharepoint groups, is to access the user list @ `/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0` inside the site collection's root web and remove the user name from there.. so will the answer for my first question depend on whether the username is removed from the `/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0` user list or not?

Third Question. which is less important to me, is it a bad practice to delete a guest user account from the `/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0` after removing his account from office 365 admin site?

Comment: For your first question, from what I tested Yesterday, old membership won't link to new one, but it will also prevent you from sharing the same website with the same guest as long as you haven't cleaned your site memberships (step in 2nd question). It is unclear if MS at some points clean old memberships, but you better do it if you don't want not being able to add the same guest to a website.